# Error with self-defined function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

I'm trying to get a UILabel.text to adopt an NSString self defined function but are stumped with the error. I am still a newbie with iOS but my gut feeling says its something to do with syntax.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    //Creating scrollable view
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];

    //Inserting Title
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [title setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40)];
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    title.text = self.setQuestion;<-error
    [scrollView addSubview:title];
    [title release];
}
- (void) setQuestion{
    NSString *qn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What do you get with%@", 5];

}
```

Thanx in advance...

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can't assign a method to an NSString*.

Answer (score 2):

`title.text = [self setQuestion];`

But `setQuestion` is improperly coded.  Should be:

```
- (NSString*) setQuestion{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What do you get with %d", 5];
}
```

And don't forget to include the prototype of `setQuestion` in your .h file.

(Well, actually, the format string is improperly coded too.  Should be "What do you get with %d".)

Comment: Incidentally, this method isn't actually setting anything, so a better name would be something like `textForQuestion`.

Comment: The reason is because the 'question' part is just the tip of the ice berg. I have to also provide the choices that comes with the question. So i dun think i can use the (NSString *). It has to be NSArray...

Comment: @TeamStar -- Then you can't assign the result directly to the `text` attribute, but must index the array somehow, or concatenate the values into a single string.

Comment: @HotLicks - Precisely... I managed to solve it using NSArray... :)